# pandas plot(kind='line') creating scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot a `pandas` `Series` with a line.
These lines produce the output shown and a scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
...
print(type(sam))
print(sam)
sam.plot(kind='line');

0.25.3
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
3300    0.87
3301    0.87
3302    0.87
3303    0.87
3304    0.87
Name: A, dtype: float64

<<SCATTER PLOT>>
```

I was not able to create a line plot by any means with `Series.plot`.

**What is the correct way of doing it?**

PS: I can conceive workarounds, like creating new `np` arrays, lists, etc.
But I guess this should work right away.

PS2: I am using Jupyter Lab under Chrome from PortableApps.
Strange thing, in one tab in the lab (with few things), the lines above produce a line plot, in another tab (with `sklearn` loaded), it produces a scatter plot.
I will experiment a little further.

Comment: give us a data sample :)

Comment: @Terry - Please see updated OP (I do not know how can the update help, anyway...)

Comment: using you data and code, i get a horizontal line fixed at .87 on y axis

Comment: @Terry - That is the point. What you get is what is expected. The question is then where should I look to fix this...

Comment: Maybe update pandas? on my test i used pandas 0.25.1

Comment: `plt.show`? what backend are you using?

Comment: @Terry - Please see updated OP-

Comment: @warped - How to test the backend?

Comment: `import matplotlib` `matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: @warped - `module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline
`.

Comment: Is this a proper way to replicate your problem in Jupyter?
`%matplotlib inline`
`import matplotlib, sklearn, pandas as pd; sam = pd.Series([0.87] * 5, index=range(3300,3305)); print(type(sam)); print(sam); sam.plot(kind='line');`

Comment: Please provide a full example with imports etc. so it can be replicated. How did you import sklearn for example

Comment: Could you upload the full broken code, your problem is still not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a line carried around from a time I knew much less about `matplotlib` than now, which was

```
plt.rcParams['lines.marker'] = 'o'
```

All I had to do is remove it (actually, I replaced that with `plt.rcParams['scatter.marker'] = 'o'`).

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
sam = pd.Series([.87,.87,.87,.87,.87], index=range(3300, 3305))
```

Series:

```
3300    0.87
3301    0.87
3302    0.87
3303    0.87
3304    0.87
dtype: float64
```

Line plot:

```
sam.plot()
```

[image]

`sam.plot(kind='line')` renders the same output.

Comment: I just tried that with Jupyter and this is working, not sure how OP got the scatter plot behavior.

Comment: This is essentially the same as posted in the OP, so it did not clarify the issue...